# How to bind Circle CenterX and Slider Value

Tags: javafx

Got problem when I tried to bind a slider with a circle `centerX`, and don't know how to solve it... So the ball has to go from left to right, with an animation(i guess that an animation is the best solution for that) and the slider has to return the ball somewhere in the scene, but the slider doesn't follow the movement of the ball while the animation is playing... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to bind two values together you need to use `bindBidirectional` method instead of `bind`. Also when you put a node in a container like the `BorderPane` it layouts the children based on some rules. If you want to manage the position of the circle yourself you will have to specify the intention with `cr.setManaged(false)`.